# Package to help display status of each git repo contained in a common directory

Tags: magit, dired, git

I have a directory and in the directory is a rather long list of git repositories.  Is there a package or options where a `dired` listing of the directory would also add in the status of each git repo contain.  For example if the git repo is clean and synced, it would show green.  If the repo has local changes, it would show red.  Or... perhaps another method could be used to indicate the current state of the repo.

I have magit installed so that might be an aid in this quest.

Answer (score 2):

[`dired-k`](https://github.com/syohex/emacs-dired-k) and [`dired-git-info`](https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/dired-git-info.html) show information about *files* within a repository in Dired. Not what you asked for but you might find these packages useful anyway.

If your repositories are actually submodules of an outer repository, then these packages should show information about the repositories themselves too. If not, then I would consider that a bug.

Magit provides some support for showing information about a list of repositories, but it doesn't use the Dired interface to do so. See [List Repositories](https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Repository-List.html).

Comment: thanks (again). The magit list repositories looks very promising.  Somehow, that led me to git work trees and they look really cool as well.